# Why fetch method can't fetch anything?(feat node.js, restAPI)

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest

I'm a newbie in node.js and mySQL
I do clone coding restaurant site.
So I made databases and I make server.

```
var app=express();


app.listen(9999,function(){ //I'm using 9999 port and I use Localhost
    console.log('Server is running');
})

//connect mySQL
var client=mysql.createConnection({
    user:'root',
    password:'pswd' //for Question
});
```

I use 9999 port and I open my server on localhost.

and I have html. It's just test html file(minuk_test.html)
and when I request to ''/store/restaurant_info', I want to recieve data by using json.

-- main.js --

```
app.get('/store/restaurant_info',function(request,response){
    client.query('SELECT * FROM RESTAURANT_INFO',function(error,result,fields){
        if(error){
            console.log('Query syntax error');
        }else{
            response.json(result);
            console.dir(result[0].name);
            console.log('check sending data');
        }
    });
});

app.get('/Project/html/minuk_test.html',function(request,response){
    fs.readFile('../html/minuk_test.html','utf-8',function(error,data){
        if(error){
            console.log('Loading minuk_test.html is failed');
        }
        response.send(data);
    })
})
```

and it's my html code.
-- html file--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>API TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/minuks_test.js">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div id="restaurant">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and it's my javascript

--javscript file--

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

function getAPI(){
    const url=`http://127.0.0.1:9999/store/restaurant_info`;
    fetch(url)
        .then(response=>{
            console.log(response);
            response.json();
        })
        .then(data={
            console.log(data);
        });
}

getAPI();
```

I expect when I enter "minuk_test.html", html execute javascript file.
In javascript file, request to url buy using get.

but I have two problem.

first, I run my server. and enter localhost:9999/Project/html/minuk_test.html
if html run javascript file. and javascript file request to /store/restaurant_info.
then server console print result[0].name and 'check sending data' but console is clear.

Second, I run javascript file with server turned on.
then console.log(response) is here

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    stream: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    boundary: null,
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
    type: 'default',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9999/store/restaurant_info',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: {
      connection: 'close',
      'content-length': '8035',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      date: 'Mon, 30 May 2022 11:53:15 GMT',
      etag: 'W/"1f63-IYBGYq/MlY5TBn49Gp7cFQ7aH+A"',
      'x-powered-by': 'Express'
    },
    counter: 0,
    highWaterMark: 16384
  }
}

undefined //console.log(data);
```

response.size is 0. is it normal?
and console.log(data) is undefined

but in postman,
[image]

postman can recieve json data.

I can't understand why my html can't receive json.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because there's no javascript file included in the html file, and it's not included because you're not serving static files on the web server, so nothing runs (also, it's not `stylesheet`, but `script` tag)

it should work if you inline javascript. Also, in the browser you use `fetch`, and `node-fetch` on the server-side):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>API TEST</title>
    <script>
        function getAPI(){
            const url=`http://127.0.0.1:9999/store/restaurant_info`;
            fetch(url)
                .then(response=>{
                    console.log(response);
                    response.json();
                })
                .then(data={
                    console.log(data);
                });
        }

        getAPI();        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div id="restaurant">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but you should setup static files, see here:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Also, you can setup your own route, without extension, and also you can use `.sendFile` to serve specific file instead of `fs`, but you need to provide absolute path (via `path` module):

see here:

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

```
app.get('/my-route', function(request, response, next) {

    response.sendFile(require('path').join(__dirname, '../html/minuk_test.html'), function(err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err)
        } else {
            console.log('Sent:', fileName)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. Your answer was very helpful to me